# Ошибка в классе. Использование do..while

Tags: javascript

```js
'use strict';
class Car {
  constructor(maxSpeed, speed, isOn, distance, price) {
    this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.isOn = isOn;
    this.distance = distance;
    this.price = price;
  }

  static getSpecs(car) {
    // console.log(maxSpeed, speed, isOn, distance, price);

    return this.maxSpeed, this.speed, this.isOn, this.distance, this.price;
  }

  get turnOn() {
    return this.price;
  }

  set turnOn(price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

  /*
   * Добавь геттер и сеттер для свойства price,
   * который будет работать с свойством цены автомобиля.
   */

  /*
   * Добавь код для того чтобы завести автомобиль
   * Записывает в свойство isOn значение true
   */
  turnOn() {
    this.isOn = true;
  }

  /*
   * Добавь код для того чтобы заглушить автомобиль
   * Записывает в свойство isOn значение false,
   * и сбрасывает текущую скорость в 0
   */

  turnOff() {
    this.isOn = false;
    this.speed = 0;
  }
  /*
   * Добавялет к свойству speed полученное значение,
   * при условии что результирующая скорость
   * не больше чем значение свойства maxSpeed
   */
  accelerate(value) {
    // this.speed += value;
    // while (this.speed < this.maxSpeed) {
    //   // console.log('counter: ', counter);
    //   // this.speed += value;
    // }

    this.speed > this.maxSpeed;
    this.speed += value;
  }

  /*
   * Добавялет к свойству speed полученное значение,
   * при условии что результирующая скорость
   * не больше чем значение свойства maxSpeed
   */
  decelerate(value) {
    this.speed -= value;
    this.speed !== 0;
  }

  /*
   * Добавляет в поле distance киллометраж (hours * speed),
   * но только в том случае если машина заведена!
   */
  drive(hours) {
    this.distance = hours * speed;
  }
}
const mustang = new Car({ maxSpeed: 200, price: 2000 });

mustang.turnOn();
mustang.accelerate(50);
mustang.drive(2);

Car.getSpecs(mustang);
// maxSpeed: 200, speed: 50, isOn: true, distance: 100, price: 2000

mustang.decelerate(20);
mustang.drive(1);
mustang.turnOff();

Car.getSpecs(mustang);
// maxSpeed: 200, speed: 0, isOn: false, distance: 120, price: 2000

console.log(mustang.price); // 2000
mustang.price = 4000;
console.log(mustang.price); // 4000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Качество Ваших вопросов повышается на глазах :).

```
drive(hours) {
  this.distance = hours * this.speed; // !!! this.speed
}
```

Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

---

```
accelerate(value) {
  if (this.speed + value <= this.maxSpeed) {
    this.speed += value;
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

```
constructor(options) {
  this.maxSpeed = options.maxSpeed || 0;
  this.speed = options.speed || 0;
  this.isOn = options.isOn || false;
  this.distance = options.distance || 0;
  this.price = options.price || 0;
}
```

Comment: но я все еще не могу понять стоит ли использовать цыкл? подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: за качество вопросов отдельное спасибо)

Comment: @hzybodska Использование цикла - не самоцель, а средство. Где Вы хотите его использовать?

Comment: в методах decelerate(value) и  accelerate(value)

Comment: @hzybodska Посмотрите мой вариант метода `accelerate`. Переделайте метод `decelerate` аналогичным образом.

Comment: метод  decelerate(value) - /*
   * Отнимает от свойства speed полученное значение,
   * при условии что результирующая скорость не меньше нуля
   */

Comment: decelerate(value) {
    

    if (this.speed - value !== 0) {
      this.speed += value;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

Comment: и еще не виводится статический метод static getSpecs(car)

Comment: @hzybodska Код совершенно не соответсвует описанию.

Comment: не выводится  static getSpecs(car) в консоль

Comment: сори) голова уже плохо работает

Comment: @hzybodska Отметьте ответ галочкой и идите спать.

Comment: Вы правы толку все равно нет) мозг не работает)спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 1):

```js
'use strict';
class Car {
  constructor(Car) {
  
    this.maxSpeed = Car.maxSpeed || 0;
    this.speed = Car.speed || 0;
    this.isOn = Car.isOn || false;
    this.distance = Car.distance || 0;
    this.price = Car.price || 0;
  }

  static getSpecs(car) {
    console.log(car);

    // return this.maxSpeed, this.speed, this.isOn, this.distance, this.price;
  }

  get turnOn() {
    return this.price;
  }

  set turnOn(price) {
    this.price || 0;
  }

  /*
   * Добавь геттер и сеттер для свойства price,
   * который будет работать с свойством цены автомобиля.
   */

  /*
   * Добавь код для того чтобы завести автомобиль
   * Записывает в свойство isOn значение true
   */
  turnOn() {
    this.isOn || false;
  }

  /*
   * Добавь код для того чтобы заглушить автомобиль
   * Записывает в свойство isOn значение false,
   * и сбрасывает текущую скорость в 0
   */

  turnOff() {
    this.isOn || false;
    this.speed = 0;
  }
  /*
   * Добавялет к свойству speed полученное значение,
   * при условии что результирующая скорость
   * не больше чем значение свойства maxSpeed
   */
 

  accelerate(value) {
    if (this.speed + value <= this.maxSpeed) {
      this.speed += value;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  /*
   * Отнимает от свойства speed полученное значение,
   * при условии что результирующая скорость не меньше нуля
   */
  decelerate(value) {
    this.speed -= value;
    this.speed !== 0;
    if (this.speed - value !== 0) {
      this.speed += value;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  /*
   * Добавляет в поле distance киллометраж (hours * speed),
   * но только в том случае если машина заведена!
   */
  drive(hours) {
    this.distance = hours * this.speed;
  }
}
const mustang = new Car({ maxSpeed: 200, price: 2000 });

mustang.turnOn();
mustang.accelerate(50);
mustang.drive(2);

Car.getSpecs(mustang);
// maxSpeed: 200, speed: 50, isOn: true, distance: 100, price: 2000

mustang.decelerate(20);
mustang.drive(1);
mustang.turnOff();

Car.getSpecs(mustang);
// maxSpeed: 200, speed: 0, isOn: false, distance: 120, price: 2000

console.log(mustang.price); // 2000
mustang.price = 4000;
console.log(mustang.price); // 4000
```

Comment: `if (this.speed - value >= 0) {
      this.speed -= value;`

Comment: Привет) спасибо что подметили , я так уже сделала)